# How to change apartment model in already existing Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com, apartments

I have a Visual C++ 2013 project that was created using COM wizard. When creating this component Apartment model was chosen. 
Is there any way to change this model to different apartment without recreating the project from scratch?

Comment: Create two projects from scratch, with different models. Diff the files. Manually transfer the difference over to your real project.

Comment: I found that there is *.rgs file in solution directory that contains ThreadingModel variable that can be changed to wanted value.

Comment: You should start with stating whether this Is a DLL or EXE project? Also worth mentioning things you have inside - COM objects, ActiveX controls etc.